# Convert the string content into an XMLStreamReader

Tags: java

Hi I would like to know how we can convert the string content which is in the form of XML tag and I need to convert it into XMLStreamReader

Comment: Do you mean convert it _using_ an XMLStreamReader? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbex/index.html

Comment: @Jayan: What did your search (or Javadoc check) find?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet -my mistake. My quick lookup showed couple of more classes with same name. (commons-io lib was one). My question was not useful ..

Answer (score 39):

You can use [`XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLStreamReader%28java.io.Reader%29), passing in a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) to wrap your string.

```
String text = "<foo>This is some XML</foo>";
Reader reader = new StringReader(text);
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); // Or newFactory()
XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
```

Comment: Don't forget to close readers (reader.close() and xmlReader.close()).

Comment: @userrg: There's no need to do that for a `StringReader`... nor, I'd imagine, for an `XMLStreamReader` which is reading from a `StringReader`. There are no native handles to close.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to read XML content from a `String` via an `XMLStreamReader`. You can do that like this:

```
public XMLStreamReader readXMLFromString(final String xmlContent)
{
    final XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlContent);
    return inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Intialize XMLInputFactory
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

//Reading from xml file and creating XMLStreamReader
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
               file));
String currentElement = "";

//Reading all the data
while(reader.hasNext()) {
   int next = reader.next();
   if(next == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)
       currentElement = reader.getLocalName();
   //System.out.println(currentElement);
}
```