# XMLStreamReader.getLocation() returns unexpected character offset

Tags: java, xml, stax, xerces

Given the following code:

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var document = "<foo>bar</foo>";
        try (var is = new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            var reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(is);
            System.out.println(reader.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
Line number = 1
Column number = 1
System Id = null
Public Id = null
Location Uri= null
CharacterOffset = 0
```

but instead it's

```
Line number = 1
Column number = 1
System Id = null
Public Id = null
Location Uri= null
CharacterOffset = 4
```

I'm very curious about the **CharacterOffset = 4** which makes no sense to me.

Can someone explain why it's **4**?

Edit: It's always 4 regardless of the root element (`<foo` or `<foobar` both the same)

(And furthermore: i need a reliable info about Element/Tag positions of the xml to perform later some DataBuffer slicing based on that information)

Running using

- Zulu JDK 17
- com.sun.org.apache.xerces Implementation

Comment: You can just run a debugger and look what it does, but at a guess, I think it consumes some characters initially to see if there is an XML declaration or not, and then maybe to see if there is a root element (`<foo` is four characters).

Comment: Events in Windows run on timers and you get whatever is in the buffer when the event reads the buffer.  It doesn't read line by line.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I started to debug but couldn't find what I was looking for due to that many abstractions, but I'll give it a another try tomorrow.

Comment: @jdweng besides I'm running on macos, I don't get the relationship as this should entirely run inside the jvm. Even when reading from filesystem or somewhere else I'd suspect that the `getLocation()` method should return a useful position info like it does for row and column and not a offset from probably a internal buffer that already read ahead. The root of my question is probably "how could i get reliable information about element positions if not via getLocation"?

Comment: You should probably be using `StringReader` btw

Comment: "_CharacterOffset = 4_" - I can't explain that - but a clue may be in the fact that if you use a different charset (for example UTF-16), you get a different offset.

Comment: See also [Convert the string content into an XMLStreamReader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733516), which uses `StringReader` as @g00se suggests. That gives an offset of 0 using your modified code with your data sample.

Comment: I'm going to guess if you dump that byte array (which shouldn't be used) before using it, you will find that a BOM has been prepended

Comment: @g00se `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` on a string does not add a BOM.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah ok. I was probably thinking of something else I did recently where I found a BOM unexpectedly

Comment: I seem to get accurate location info running openjdk 21 on ubuntu 22.04. However, the docs are pretty obvious on that this info is optional (and hence not reliable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Summary:*

I am using [Adoptium's Temurin](https://adoptium.net/) Java 21.

As shown in [Convert the string content into an XMLStreamReader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733516/12567365), use a `StringReader`. This does not have the problems you are seeing with inaccurate offsets.

---

*More details regarding the results you are seeing...*

**1) Explicitly declare the encoding**

When declaring your `XMLStreamReader`, if you use a `ByteArrayInputStream`, you should explicitly provide the encoding you want to use.

So, instead of this:

```java
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory
        .newDefaultFactory()
        .createXMLStreamReader(is);
```

You can use this:

```java
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory
        .newDefaultFactory()
        .createXMLStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
```

(Here, I replaced your `var` with the explicit class `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader`.)

You can see the JavaDoc for this method here: [`XMLInputFactory::createXMLStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String)).

The method requires you to use a string. I expect the class predates `StandardCharsets` - or otherwise does not use this preferred approach.

You may think you have already declared the encoding when defining the byte array input stream:

```java
new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

And indeed you have - but the `XMLInputFactory` does not make use of this. It needs to be told explicitly, as shown above.

---

**2. Auto-detecting the encoding**

Behind the scenes, Xerces uses the following class:

```java
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager
```

This class uses whatever explicit encoding you have defined to build an appropriate byte array handler (which knows how the bytes have been encoded).

If you do not pass an explicit encoding (like the code in the question doesn't), then `XMLEntityManager` tries to auto-detect the encoding from the start of the byte stream. It first checks to see if a BOM has been used.

You can see that in the source code [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dea94f4445b9389339cf7ca0eef688ca56c17814/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityManager.java#L714):

```java
// perform auto-detect of encoding if necessary
if (encoding == null) {
    // read first four bytes and determine encoding
    final byte[] b4 = new byte[4];
    int count = 0;
    for (; count<4; count++ ) {
        b4[count] = (byte)rewindableStream.readAndBuffer();
    }
    .... // rest of code not shown here
```

This consumes **the first 4 bytes** of your XML data stream.

The stream is reset, if there is no BOM:

```java
stream.reset();
```

However, the `readAndBuffer()` method shown above is called 4 times in that `for` loop - and that method increments the offset variable: `fOffset++;` - you can see that [in the source code here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dea94f4445b9389339cf7ca0eef688ca56c17814/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityManager.java#L3101).

So, whereas the stream is reset, the offset state is not.

That is where your result comes from:

```
CharacterOffset = 4
```

---

**3. What if you provide an explicit charset of "UTF-8"?**

In that case, the code uses this info [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dea94f4445b9389339cf7ca0eef688ca56c17814/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityManager.java#L753).

In this case, the code again checks for a BOM, but uses a 3-byte array for this (for a 3-byte UTF-8 BOM):

```java
final int[] b3 = new int[3];
```

So, in this case my version of your code produces this output, for the same basic reason as mentioned above:

```
CharacterOffset = 3
```

This time, the offset is 3, not 4. As above, the stream is reset; but the offset tracker is not reset.

---

**4. What if you use `StringReader`?**

In this case, the `org.xml.sax.InputSource` class will use the following to manage your input source:

```java
public InputSource (Reader characterStream)
{
    setCharacterStream(characterStream);
}
```

In fact you can use any of the `Reader` subclasses - including `StringReader`.

In these cases, the byte checking logic (described above) [is bypassed](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dea94f4445b9389339cf7ca0eef688ca56c17814/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityManager.java#L656). Therefore the offset remains accurate.

Here is an example with a buffered reader and a char array reader:

```java
var is = new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(document.toCharArray()));
```

This gives:

```
CharacterOffset = 0
```

---

I don't know whether this rises to the level of a bug, or is just a feature of how Xerces works - and was *designed* to work.